# Visual Studio Express 2012 complains "Web project component not installed" when opening a .csproj file

Tags: visual-studio, components

I have just installed Windows Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop. I am now trying to open a `.csproj` file. When doing so, I get the complaint:

> Web project component not installed. Unable to upgrade project: [file].csproj

What does this mean? How do I install the "Web project component"? More generally, how do I install "components"? What are they and where are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you don't install Web component, i had the same problem

Link : http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web

Comment: I'am happy to help you eegg

Comment: So can I ask, must we install both "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop" and "...for Web" separately? And they don't mind being installed that way?

Comment: you can install two instance separatelly , it's not problem, it's my case